# How to apply my custom theme's color to a Vuetify switch component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vuetifyjs3

I'm using **Vuetify 3.0.4** with Vue 3 and I want to apply a custom color via a custom theme to my `<v-switch>`. I want to apply my custom primary color to it.

What doesn't seem to work:

```
<v-switch theme="myTheme" color="primary" inset></v-switch>
```

I defined my theme as:

```
const myTheme = {
  dark: true,
  colors: {
    background: '#212126',
    surface: '#000',
    primary: '#fd8118',
    // more colors
  },
};

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      myTheme,
    },
  },
  components,
  directives,
});

createApp(App).use(router).use(store).use(vuetify).mount('#app');
```

However I'm able to apply my primary color to a button, so the theme should be set up correctly:

```
<v-btn theme="myTheme" color="primary">This button has the correct color</v-btn>
```

Also I can change the switch's color to be a default one:

```
// this works
<v-switch color="orange" inset></v-switch>
```

Comment: Vuetify 3 is not yet production ready. Either stick to Vuetify 2 or switch to Quasar 2. Or, eventually wait until Vuetify 3 becomes more mature. Or, as a last resort - debug the issue and create a PR with the fix for Vuetify.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you're right and that will be fixed. The problem is Vuetify V2 does not support Vue V3 which is used on our project.
Maybe I really should create that PR. :))

Comment: Perhaps if you change the colors in the default theme (either `light` or `dark`) - Vuetify might pick them up?

Answer (score 0):

while you are creating the theme you are not setting it as the default theme as shown in the documentation [here](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/)

below example should work for you

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createVuetify, ThemeDefinition } from 'vuetify'

const myTheme = {
  dark: true,
  colors: {
    background: '#212126',
    surface: '#000',
    primary: '#fd8118',
    // more colors
  },
}

export default createVuetify({
  theme: {
    defaultTheme: 'myTheme',
    themes: {
      myCustomLightTheme,
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried that too, but does not work. `theme="myTheme"` set on the `v-switch` should also do the job.